# Easiest way to redirect multiple domains to a single domain with HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https

My company has several domains, some with dozens of subdomains, that are currently all pointing to a single IIS server.  The domains are all covered by a single cert.  I am looking for an easy way to setup a maintenance website(basically just an image) that all of them will be redirected to when we take the server down for maintenance.

We use AWS and I started going down the route of setting up a static website on S3 and using cloudfront to serve it over HTTPS but that requires a bucket for each domain/subdomain, which is not really feasible...

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Make one S3 bucket and CloudFront distribution for `maintenance.example.com`.

**Option 1: Changing DNS Records**

When performing maintenance, update your DNS with CNAME records for each of your sites (i.e. `app.example.com` to `maintenance.example.com`). When you’re done, update DNS again.

As pointed out by @Remy Lebeau, DNS will take time to propagate.

**Option 2: Have Application Servers Redirect To Cloudfront**

Configure the application server to redirect to `maintenance.example.com` when is receives a request. When done with maintenance, revert this behavior.

Comment: DNS updates take time to propagate through the Internet, though.  Maybe more time than the actual maintenance will take.  Having the server deliver a maintenance reply, preferably an HTTP 307 redirect, to any HTTP request is the better option.

Comment: I suppose I was assuming a more long term maintenance, where the propagation time will not matter. I will update the answer with your approach as well.